# Can you use external resources in Cucumber feature "Examples:" section?

Tags: selenium, automation, cucumber, gherkin

Here is my test feature file with one scenario

```
Feature: My test feature

Scenario Outline: I want user to be logged into MyPage

When user goes to MyPage
And user fills "<test_login>" login field
And user fills "<test_password>" password field
And user clicks Login button
Then user should be logged in

Examples:
|test_login|test_password|
|login1234|password1234|
```

I would like to modify my Examples: section to something like this

```
Examples:
src/test/resources/datatables/logind_data.table
```

I want to use a path to file that contains data table but I get Cucumber gherkins builder error message.
[error_modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yQwoQ.png)

Is it possible to use external resources in "Examples:"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is currently not possible. We're discussing how to implement is in [this issue](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/issues/773). Feel free to join the conversation over there.

Answer (score 0):

Cucumber is not supporting any external file now.
This is not possible. However you can try to use properties file in cucumber code and initialize it.
But again, you cannot keep all data in properties file

Answer (score 0):

The best way to this sort of thing is to write better scenarios which abstract out the details.

But first of all you need to answer some questions.

Why do you need to test that lost of different users can log into the system?
What benefit do you get from testing the extra users?

Assuming you actually have a good reason to test a group of users, you could write something like

```
Scenario: Foo users can sign in
  Given Foo users are registered
  When Foo users sign in
  Then Foo users should have signed in
```

And push all the details about how you do this down into your step definitions. This will allow you to do things like

```
Given 'Foo users are registered' do
  @foo_users = load_foo_users(path: src/test/resources/datatables/logind_data.table)
  @foo_users.each do |user|
    register_user(user: user)
  end
 end
```

You can loop around the users in the when step and record the results in another global. And then examine the results in the Then step.

There are a couple of general techniques in use here

- push the how down the test stack (features, step_defs, helper_methods, application code)
- use global variables to communicate between steps
- use abstract simple language in scenarios
- names constructs and refer to them by name in scenarios. Do not define their contents.